# Trying to create a file to save an image Java

Tags: java, file-io, io, javax.imageio

I get the following exception when trying to create a file on windows 7 using Java. An example of a path is "C:/g-ecx/images-amazon/com/images/G/01/gno/images/orangeBlue/navPackedSprites-US-22.*V183711641*.png". If I hard code in a path it does work however. I've been banging my head for two hours, can anyone help.

mkdir fails but doesn't through an exception, create file throws the exception.

```
java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified
at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:883)
at org.willmanning.mtt.html.processingbehavior.ImageProcessingBehavior.processImage(ImageProcessingBehavior.java:125)
at org.willmanning.mtt.html.processingbehavior.ImageProcessingBehavior.loadImages(ImageProcessingBehavior.java:99)
at org.willmanning.mtt.html.processingbehavior.ImageProcessingBehavior.processNodes(ImageProcessingBehavior.java:66)
at org.willmanning.mtt.html.processingbehavior.ImageProcessingBehavior.processRootNode(ImageProcessingBehavior.java:34)
at org.willmanning.mtt.html.ParsingFacade.processURL(ParsingFacade.java:38)
at org.willmanning.mtt.App.main(App.java:45)



 /**
 * 
 * @param image
 * @param url
 */
public void processImage(BufferedImage image, URL url) {

    StringBuilder path = new StringBuilder();
    path.append("C:/Users/will/Documents/");
    path.append(url.getHost().replace('.', '/'));
    path.append(url.getFile());
    path.replace(path.lastIndexOf("."), path.length(), ".txt");

    File file = new File(path.toString());

    boolean mkdir = file.mkdir();

    boolean isNew = false;
    try {
        isNew = file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    /*
     * only create the file if it doesn't exist
     */
    if (isNew) {
        try {
            ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using

```
boolean mkdir = file.mkdirs();
```

instead of

```
boolean mkdir = file.mkdir();
```

[mkdirs()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29) creates the whole parent path/directories if needed:

Comment: So that seemed to work but what happens now is it creates a folder (from the example path) called "navPackedSprites-US-22.V183711641.png" and my createFile call returns false.

Comment: SO I have it working, I need to chop up my path a bit more into directory and file parts, it assumes that image.gif is a folder name.